# Помогите скорректировать код

Tags: c++

Имеется два класса, один из которых имеет методы, которые дружественны другому классу, но из-за того, что первый имеет в себе объект второго я не знаю как правильно разместить их в header. Если вписывать сначала `Koords` а потом `Complexity`, то компилятор не видит дружественные функции, а если наоборот (как ниже), то ошибкой подсвечивается объявление объекта типа `Koords` в классе `Complexity`. Что делать?

```
class Koords;

class Complexity {
private:
    Koords sizes_;//сдесь выдает ошибку
    unsigned short mines_;
public:
    explicit Complexity(int = EASILY);
    auto getY() const;
    auto getX() const;
    auto getM() const;
    Koords return_sizes() const;
};

class Koords {
private:
    unsigned short y_;
    unsigned short x_;
public:
    Koords(const int y = 0, const int x = 0);
    auto getY() const;
    auto getX() const;
    friend auto Complexity::getY() const;
    friend auto Complexity::getX() const;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дружественность к методам ещё не определённого класса не будет работать. Объявление класса с ещё не определёнными типами не получится. Так-как класс **Complexity** полностью зависит от реализации **Koords**, дружественность класса **Koords** к методам *дочернего* класса **Complexity** это нереализуемое счастье. Единственным выходом из сложившейся ситуации вижу только *статическое* объявление метода, дружественного с обоими классами. Причём тип **auto** придётся переделать на что-то конкретное (**unsigned short**).

```
class Complexity;

class Koords {
private:
    unsigned short y_;
    unsigned short x_;
public:
    Koords(const int y = 0, const int x = 0);
    unsigned short getY() const;
    unsigned short getX() const;
    friend unsigned short getY(Complexity const & ) ;
    friend unsigned short getX(Complexity const & ) ;
};

class Complexity {
private:
    Koords sizes_;
    unsigned short mines_;
public:
    explicit Complexity(int = EASILY);
    friend unsigned short getY(Complexity const & ) ;
    friend unsigned short getX(Complexity const & ) ;
    auto getM() const;
    Koords return_sizes() const;
};

unsigned short getY(Complexity const & ) ;
unsigned short getX(Complexity const & ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявить другом весь класс Complexity

```
class Koords {
    ...
    friend class Complexity;
    ...
};
```

Тогда Complexity может быть объявлен где угодно или его может вообще не быть. А вообще незачем тут напрямую за координатами лазить, т.к. если `getX/Y` не виртуальное, е тело вырождается до `return x_;`, то компилятор тебе так наоптимизирует, что ничем от прямого доступа к x,y отличатся не будет.

Comment: Это понятно, что можно сделать другом целый класс, но мне интересно сделать друзьями именно эти функции - не больше.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Koords;
```

Компилятор не имеет ни какого предчувствия, сколько памяти нужно определить для класса Koords, и так строка

```
Koords sizes_;
```

натурально выдает ошибку, так как переменная `Koords` коммандой

```
class Koords;
```

*не определена*, она только *декларирована*.

Обычной подход - использование *указателя* на класс (его длину компилятор знает, так как длина всех указателей одинаковая, обычно 4 или 8 байтов в зависимости от операционной системы и компилятора), а не самого класса:

```
Koords *sizes_;
```